# Net 6 DLL can't load System.Runtime.Caching when called from a /clr:netcore DLL

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a .Net 6.0 class library (trtDatatypesCore.dll) that uses the package System.Runtime.Caching.  The package version is: 6.0.0.

When I call it from a .Net 6.0 console application everything loads and runs fine.

To call this DLL from a cpp executable I created a managed cpp DLL  with the following settings:

/clr:netcore
Target Framework: net6.0

When it tries to load the trtDatatypesCore.dll I get the following Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

All of my DLLs are complied and run from  a common directory.  The package dll is in my user directory.

The trtDatatypesCore.deps.json contains:

```
"runtimeTarget": {"name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0","signature": ""},"compilationOptions": {},"targets": {".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0": {"trtDatatypesCore/1.0.0": {"dependencies": {"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "6.0.0","Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "5.0.0","Newtonsoft.Json": "13.0.1","System.Runtime.Caching": "6.0.0","WinSCP": "5.19.6"},"runtime": {"trtDatatypesCore.dll": {}}},And

  "System.Runtime.Caching/6.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager": "6.0.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "lib/net6.0/System.Runtime.Caching.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "6.0.21.52210"
      }
    },
```

I created test console applications (both c++ and NetCore) to test the calling of the c# library to remove the possibility of another version of the DLL being loaded elsewhere.

I verified my Configuration Manager settings are:

Debug: x86
C++ Projects- Platform = WIn32
Core Projects- Platform = Any CPU

Edit:
I deleted the package and referenced the DLL directly with the 'copy local' set.  The dll was copied into the directory with all the other dlls.  Same result.